# D3 transition doesn't add new bar to the DOM

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I add or remove a data element, the axes update correctly. It also looks like the "bars" object is updated with the correct the "x" and "height" values, but changes don't show up in the DOM.

Here's the update function:

```
updateChart: function() {
  var chart = this,
      xScale = this.scales.x,
      yScale = this.scales.y,
      data = this.collection.toJSON()
      padding = this.config.barPadding;

  xScale.domain(chart.collection.pluck(chart.config.xAttr));
  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(chart.collection.pluck(chart.config.yAttr))]).nice();

  var bars = this.svg.select(".bar").data(data);
  bars.exit().remove();
  bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("id",     function(d) { return "bar-" + d[chart.config.xAttr]; })
    .attr("data-x", function(d) { return d[chart.config.xAttr]; })
    .attr("data-y", function(d) { return d[chart.config.yAttr]; });

  chart.svg.select(".x.axis").transition().duration(1000).call(chart.xAxis);
  chart.svg.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(1000).call(chart.yAxis);
  bars.transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d[chart.config.xAttr]); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d[chart.config.yAttr]); })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return chart.height - yScale(d[chart.config.yAttr]); });
  console.log(bars);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the correct values are being set if the changes don't show up in the DOM?

Comment: I'm dumping the bars object to the console.

Comment: OK, I'm an idiot. Line 11 should be `selectAll(".bar")`. Nevermind.